# Повредился index при перебоях электроэнергии

Tags: html, css

Как исправить эту проблему?

Сегодня после потери сети электропитания повредился документ index. Сам размер файла (72 кб) остался тем же, но при открытии редактором выдаёт ошибку, стандартный блокнот и прочие канцелярские программы открывают пустой документ. При открытии файла через браузер так же всё пусто.

Comment: Боюсь, уже никак. Меня в аналогичной ситуации спасло то, что редактор время от времени делал резервные копии.

Comment: Какой редактор
і какая страніца ссилка
ето файл с робочего сайта?

Comment: посмотрите в кеше редактора, если не повредилась и локальная версия файла

Comment: если он открил файл то он скорее всево перезатьорса, 
если ето сайт в публичном доступе посмотрите в кеше у google

Comment: Как вариант можешь залить на фтп и открыть с него, может сработать но не гарант

Comment: @vov4ok в кеше у гугла будет отрендеренная страница, а если у него index.php

Comment: @Sergey Novikov ето одно с предположений

Comment: Смотря какой редактор.

Comment: Советую купить ноутбук, тысяч 40 того стоят.

Comment: Попробуй так: пкм -> свойства -> предыдущие  версии

Answer (score 0):

Если использовал для редактирования кода Notepad++ можешь восстановить документ с кэша по ссылке C:\Users{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++